# gpd.overlay throws IntCastingNaNError

Tags: python, geopandas

Using Geopandas 0.10.2 `gpd.overlay` throws error.
Where using  Geopandas 0.9.0 there will be no error.

```
df3 = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='symmetric_difference')


File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\agrigis\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 1168, in astype_nansafe
return astype_float_to_int_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)

File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\agrigis\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 1213, in astype_float_to_int_nansafe
raise IntCastingNaNError(

**IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer**
```

Rather large dataset, so I don't  know where are those NAs that throw the Problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem are the Nas values ; `Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer**`

Comment: Did also  df.fillna(0) for boths DataFrames, and still not working. But Thanks for reply

Comment: It is a Pandas error  ([pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.errors.IntCastingNaNError.html)) not a GeoPandas error

Comment: Did you check if there are any rows with missing geometries? If so, filling those rows with `0` will still cause issues.

Comment: Yes i checked that. I only keep rows with geom_type = 'Polygon'. I think it has to do with some incompatibility of the versions of Geopandas with others..?!? But i still dont really know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved for now with downgrade of pandas from 1.3.0 to 1.1.3.